# JQuery selector for ampersand character using :contains()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select the following element using the JQuery `:contains` pseudo class?

```
<div class='tab'>A & B</div>
```

I have tried the following all of which do not work.

```
$('.tab:contains("A & B")')
$('.tab:contains("A &amp; B")')
$('.tab:contains("A \0026 B")')
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/kyjkmLhr/

Comment: Well, for one thing, that's not CSS. If you're looking for a CSS-based solution as your tags imply, then [there isn't one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text).

Comment: @BoltClock mmmm, I thought it was core css.  Have updated to JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first seems to work

```js
$('.tab:contains("A & B")').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab'>A & B</div>
```

Comment: you beated me on time, +1

Comment: Don't have the code with me right now but I will try again tomorrow.  I guess it must be something else going on.  The actual data is being read from a [yadda table](https://acuminous.gitbooks.io/yadda-user-guide/content/en/feature-specs/example-tables.html).  Maybe it is doing something weird when reading the & character.